# Testing To See if Characters are Present in a Cell in R

Tags: r, dataframe

so I'm trying to find a code that will test to see if there is characters in a dataframe cell, if there is I want it to produce a binary variable with 1 if true and 0 if false. Here's what my data looks like:

```
Name
Bob
Joe

Greg

Hannah
```

Here is what I want it to look like

```
Name             True/False
Bob                  1
Joe                  1
                     0
Greg                 1
                     0
Hannah               1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
df$TrueFalse <- as.integer(nchar(df$Name) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `+`

```
 df$TrueFalse <- +(nchar(df$Name) > 0)
```